# How to pull data from an existing PostGIS database into Carto?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, carto, amazon-web-services

I have an existing PostGIS database. I want to be able to access my tables from that DB on my Carto enterprise account. Any suggestions?

Comment: point, line, or poly? export to CSV and re-import... or maybe you're using geoserver and want them to import wfs the way they can import arcgis server services...???

Answer (score 1):

to enable that feature on CARTO SaaS you need to contact our Support team and take a look at the [documentation](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/import-api/database-connectors/#the-postgresql-connector).

Disclaimer: I work at CARTO